# Rails Mysql adaptor tries to query an abstract model class which does not have a backing table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, abstract

I have a model class "Abtest" that inherits from an abstract base class "ModBase" which does not have a backing table.  When Abtest.new is called, I got the following error even though in ModBase class I have "self.abstract_class = true".  What did I do wrong?

```
class ModBase < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true

class Abtest < ModBase

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql::Error: Table 'mydb.mod_bases' doesn't exist: SHOW FIELDS FROM `mod_bases`):
  activerecord (3.1.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:435:in `query'
  activerecord (3.1.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:435:in `execute'
  activerecord (3.1.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:244:in `log'
  activesupport (3.1.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
  activerecord (3.1.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:239:in `log'
  activerecord (3.1.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:435:in `execute'
  activerecord (3.1.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:636:in `columns'
  activerecord (3.1.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:95:in `initialize'
  activerecord (3.1.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:185:in `with_connection'
  activerecord (3.1.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:92:in `initialize'
  activerecord (3.1.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:112:in `call'
  activerecord (3.1.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:112:in `default'
  activerecord (3.1.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:112:in `[]'
  activerecord (3.1.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:112:in `initialize'
  activerecord (3.1.0) lib/active_record/base.rb:717:in `call'
  activerecord (3.1.0) lib/active_record/base.rb:717:in `default'
  activerecord (3.1.0) lib/active_record/base.rb:717:in `[]'
  activerecord (3.1.0) lib/active_record/base.rb:717:in `column_defaults'
  activerecord (3.1.0) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:327:in `attributes_from_column_definition'
  activerecord (3.1.0) lib/active_record/locking/optimistic.rb:69:in `attributes_from_column_definition'
  activerecord (3.1.0) lib/active_record/base.rb:1544:in `initialize'
  app/models/abtest.rb:89:in `new'
```

Comment: If you the class has no backing table, why let it inherit from ActiveRecord?

Comment: It contains wrapper functions related to AR such as save etc.  It factors out the commonalities of the child classes which all have their separate tables.  I am not using STI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a Rails bug in 3.1.0. 
https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/558

I have upgraded to 3.1.11 and the error never happened again.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't run your migrations. Which is what this error is all about. ActiveRecord will need a table for ModBase regardless of STI. All STI does is set the "type" column.

Since it sounds like you're trying to do a table less setup... What you might be looking for is probably found in ActiveModel. Essentially you get a lot of the AR goodness without the database requirement.

[Railscast on ActiveModel](http://railscasts.com/episodes/219-active-model)